# MySQL long query, select dialogs with the last message and user for every dialog

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

After adding more logic to get anonymous messages, sql started to run slowly, so I've added composite indexes for fields:

```
alter table dialog add index anonym_ftr1(from_anonym_id, to_anonym_id, removed_uid1);
alter table dialog add index anonym_tfr2(to_anonym_id, from_anonym_id, removed_uid2);
```

SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    dialog.id AS dialog_id,
    users.id AS uid,
    users.purchases,
    name,
    number,
    avatar,
    avatar_date,
    driver,
    vehicle,
    messages.id AS mid,
    uid2,
    mid2,
    messages.msg,
    messages.removed,
    messages.from_anonym_id,
    messages.to_anonym_id,
    (messages.date DIV 1000) AS date,
    from_id = 1 AS outbox,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            messages FORCE KEY (idx_ufsr)
        WHERE
            from_id = uid && user_id = 1 && read_state = 0 && removed = 0
    ) AS not_read
FROM
    dialog,
    messages,
    users
WHERE
    messages.id = dialog.mid && users.removed != 1 && (
        (
            uid1 = 1 && users.id = uid2 && removed_uid1 = 0
        ) || (
            users.id = uid1 && uid2 = 1 && removed_uid2 = 0
        )
        OR (
            dialog.from_anonym_id = 3
            AND users.anonym_id = dialog.to_anonym_id && removed_uid1 = 0
        )
        OR (
            dialog.to_anonym_id = 3
            AND users.anonym_id = dialog.from_anonym_id && removed_uid2 = 0
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    dialog.mid DESC
LIMIT 0,21
```

show index from dialog:

```
 +--------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table  | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +--------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | dialog |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | id             | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | uid1           |            1 | uid1           | A         |      379381 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | uid1           |            2 | uid2           | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | uid2           |            1 | uid2           | A         |     1896905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | idx_mid        |            1 | mid            | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | from_anonym_id |            1 | from_anonym_id | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | to_anonym_id   |            1 | to_anonym_id   | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | mid_uid        |            1 | mid            | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | mid_uid        |            2 | uid2           | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | mid_uid        |            3 | uid1           | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | mid2           |            1 | mid2           | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | uid_removed    |            1 | uid1           | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | uid_removed    |            2 | uid2           | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | uid_removed    |            3 | removed_uid1   | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | uid_removed    |            4 | removed_uid2   | A         |     5690715 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | anonym_ftr1    |            1 | from_anonym_id | A         |         200 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | anonym_ftr1    |            2 | to_anonym_id   | A         |         200 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | anonym_ftr1    |            3 | removed_uid1   | A         |         200 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | anonym_tfr2    |            1 | to_anonym_id   | A         |         200 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | anonym_tfr2    |            2 | from_anonym_id | A         |         200 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | dialog |          1 | anonym_tfr2    |            3 | removed_uid2   | A         |         200 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    +--------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

explain extended:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: dialog
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: uid1,uid2,idx_mid,from_anonym_id,to_anonym_id,mid_uid,uid_removed,anonym_ftr1,anonym_tfr2
          key: uid1,uid2,from_anonym_id,to_anonym_id
      key_len: 4,4,4,4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 50
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using sort_union(uid1,uid2,from_anonym_id,to_anonym_id); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: users
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,removed
          key: removed
      key_len: 1
          ref: NULL
         rows: 398596
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: messages
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: anumbers.dialog.mid
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra:
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: messages
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_ufsr
          key: idx_ufsr
      key_len: 10
          ref: const,func,const,const
         rows: 3
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
4 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I have some thoughts about union, but there will be problem with sorting by mid.
Also, it is possible to split on 2 queries and sort them in array.

Come here to know, if there is a possible way to run just 1 query faster? 
Please, do me a favour post only solutions. The person, who really help with this problem - will got approved and point etc.

PS Sorry, I don't know how to adjust the table with indexes.

Comment: Thx to Rahul for editing.

Comment: A punt on my part; but have you actually checked that the optimizer is slower without the `FORCE` declaration? reference: http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/ . Also another minor detail is that yor `JOINS` are assumed rather than declared outright.

Comment: Also your `SELECT` statement has some values called by table.column and some values called by just column, I think this should be clarified as well.

Comment: Also MyISAM data and indexes suffer from fragmentation. Running `OPTIMIZE TABLE`  under MyISAM will sort and recreate the index and data files.

Comment: Martin, thx for attention, the ENGINE=InnoDB and sure I checked that the sub query is much quicker with FORCE KEY (idx_ufsr) composite key, because I've done so for optimization reasons. Also, I don't see any problem with columns naming - have nothing to do with optimization primary goal.

Comment: Please reformulate your query using `JOIN ... ON...` syntax.  Please qualify each column with the table (or alias of the table) it belongs to.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (As it stands, the code is too hard to follow.)

Comment: And please be consistent about `&&` vs `AND` -- the words are conventionally used.